# Strategy for debugging C# analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've created my own code analyzer

```
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class PluginAnalyzer : Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzer { ... }
```

During unit test pattern / error / I'm looking for is reported as it should. However when I plugin in the analyzer to real project the analysis its not getting executed - or at lest the error is not getting reported (I'm using file from this project in unit test).

E.G.:

`realproject.csproj`

```
 <PackageReference Include="MyAnalyzer" Version="1.0.0">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>analyzers</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
```

I can see the analyzer is getting executed (`csc.exe /analyzer:..MyAnalyzer.dll`) yet the error is not getting reported. Is there a way to debug the analyzer / analyze if it is getting triggered or why it is getting ignored ?

Comment: [How to debug an analyzer](https://roslyn-analyzers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-debug.html)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - that is VSIX related - and that works for me - I'm trying to understand how to debug analyzer being used during build.

Answer (score 7):

It is actually pretty straightforward:

1. Locate file where your analyzer package lives; usually its something like
   `c:\Users\[your user name]\.nuget\packages\[your package name]\[your package version]\analyzers\dotnet\cs\`
2. In your analyzer project replace the initialize method with something like

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context) {
  if (!Debugger.IsAttached) {
    Debugger.Launch();
  }
}
```

3. Build and replace the nuget package dll with modified one
4. The moment code analysis is triggered it will ask you to attach debugger